# Исправление некорректной работы магической константы __DIR__ после git pull

Tags: php, git

у меня есть рабочий проект parser - это папка с рабочим проектом и в ней папка .git
есть папка parser.git - хранилище
и есть папка parser_dev - папка содержит папку .git - это экспериментальная

Суть:
есть файл function.php в нем есть

```
include_once(__DIR__ .'/db.php');
```

когда я делаю git pull parser.git master

у меня возникает ошибка при выполнении скрипта - дословно - нельзя переопределить класс, который находится в файле function.php . Суть магической ошибки в данном случае `__DIR__` отрабатывает как путь к папке измененной в другом проекте

Иными словами когда запускаю проект parser - ссылается на parser_dev и когда запускаю проект parser_dev ссылается на проект parser

проверял права и группы в файлах - идентичны. Стоит мне добавить один символ в этом файле и `__DIR__` отрабатывает как надо. А также если вернуть изменения - убрать этот пробельный символ в любом доступном месте - вновь появляется ошибка. И что самое интересное - если ничего не менять в файле - ошибка исчезнет сама собой если перезапустить php на сервере.

Как такая магическая ошибка возможна - очень непонятно. `__DIR__` показывает папку проекта в котором он изменялся до git push parser.git master
Как это решить? если надо будет могу переформулировать вопрос.

покажите структуру ваших папок. git

```
micle@parser:/var/www/parser.git$ ls -la
total 40
drwxr-xr-x   7 micle users 4096 Aug  8  2016 .
drwxr-xr-x  15 user  root  4096 Mar 22 16:50 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 micle users 4096 Aug  8  2016 branches
-rwxr--r--   1 micle users   66 Aug  8  2016 config
-rw-r--r--   1 micle users   73 Aug  8  2016 description
-rw-r--r--   1 micle users   23 Aug  8  2016 HEAD
drwxr-xr-x   2 micle users 4096 Aug  8  2016 hooks
drwxr-xr-x   2 micle users 4096 Aug  8  2016 info
drwxr-xr-x 109 micle users 4096 Mar 22 17:27 objects
drwxr-xr-x   4 micle users 4096 Aug  8  2016 refs

micle@parser:/var/www/parser/.git$ ls -la
total 308
drwxrwxr-x   8 micle www-data   4096 Mar 22 17:55 .
drwxrwxr-x   9 user  www-data   4096 Mar 22 17:48 ..
drwxrwxr-x   2 micle www-data   4096 Aug  5  2016 branches
-rwxrwxr-x   1 micle www-data    137 Mar 22 17:55 COMMIT_EDITMSG
-rwxrwxr-x   1 micle users       190 Mar 17 10:53 config
-rwxrwxr-x   1 micle www-data     73 Aug  5  2016 description
-rwxrwxr-x   1 micle www-data     77 Mar 22 17:52 FETCH_HEAD
-rw-r--r--   1 micle users        23 Mar 22 17:48 HEAD
drwxrwxr-x   2 micle www-data   4096 Aug  5  2016 hooks
-rw-r--r--   1 micle users    254480 Mar 22 17:54 index
drwxrwxr-x   2 micle www-data   4096 Aug  5  2016 info
drwxrwxr-x   3 micle www-data   4096 Aug  5  2016 logs
drwxrwxr-x 260 micle www-data   4096 Mar 17 12:23 objects
-rw-r--r--   1 micle users        41 Mar 22 17:52 ORIG_HEAD
drwxrwxr-x   5 micle www-data   4096 Aug  8  2016 refs

micle@parser:/var/www/parser_dev/.git$ ls -la
total 304
drwxrwxr-x   8 micle users      4096 Mar 22 17:56 .
drwxrwxr-x   9 user  www-data   4096 Mar 22 17:55 ..
drwxrwxr-x   2 micle users      4096 Aug  8  2016 branches
-rwxrwxr-x   1 micle users         4 Mar 22 17:26 COMMIT_EDITMSG
-rwxrwxr-x   1 micle users       256 Mar 17 10:55 config
-rwxrwxr-x   1 micle users        73 Aug  8  2016 description
-rwxrwxr-x   1 micle users        77 Mar 22 17:55 FETCH_HEAD
-rw-r--r--   1 micle users        23 Mar 22 16:22 HEAD
drwxrwxr-x   2 micle users      4096 Aug  8  2016 hooks
-rw-r--r--   1 micle users    245912 Mar 22 17:56 index
drwxrwxr-x   2 micle users      4096 Aug  8  2016 info
drwxrwxr-x   3 micle users      4096 Aug  8  2016 logs
drwxrwxr-x 259 micle users      4096 Mar 17 14:52 objects
-rw-r--r--   1 micle users        41 Mar 22 17:55 ORIG_HEAD
-rw-r--r--   1 micle users        39 Mar 17 10:55 packed-refs
drwxrwxr-x   5 micle users      4096 Aug  8  2016 refs
```

Comment: It's a kind of magic, magic, magic....

Comment: Возможно, дело в каком-нибудь OpCache, общем для двух проектов

Comment: переформулируйте вопрос. покажите структуру ваших папок. git никакой магии не делает.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman готово - правда не пойму что вам это даст

Comment: @Mcile вы знаете о branch?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman да это ветвление - переходишь на другую ветвь и у тебя могут все файлы поменяться , я пользуюсь двумя ветками ветками в parser_dev и одной в parser

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman Обычно я делаю в parser_dev так: git checkout master; git merge develop; git push parser.git master; cd ../parser; git pull parser.git master - мне этого хватает

Comment: а зачем у вас 3 копии одного репозитория? в чем цель подобной схемы?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman ну как же: parser - эта рабочий сайт, parser_dev - это сайт разработчика - там он все видит в рамках настроенного сервера - собственно вся работа в нем и делается, а parser.git - буфер между этими двумя средами

Comment: судя по вашим словам вы не правильно используете git. обычно в репозитории есть ветки: master - это то, что продакшене, develop - это то над чем сейчас работают. по окончании работы на новым develop объединяют с master.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman дело в том что есть рабочая версия никакая смена веток там недопустима - туда лишь делается git pull parser.git master То о чем вы говорите некорректно - смена веток в рабочей версии может привести к неработоспособному проекту, поскольку все содержимое папок поменяется или вы этого не знали? И данный комент не продвигает в решении данного вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Виновником всего оказался `realpath_cache` его надо чистить или не использовать, если вы не используете массивных библиотек со множеством файлов